# Save html code to mysql table with php and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Im trying to clone a div's content with jquery. After it is cloned i am sending it to a php page to be processed with Jquery Ajax. The php page saves it to a mysql database table. Then i need to retrieve it from the table on a different page and load it in another div. The mysql table cell is a blob that i save this html too. When i retrieve the table it echo's [object Object]. So i not usre if i am sending it to the save_invoice.php correctly or im not saving it to database correctly or last im not retrieving it correctly.

Html div: invoice.php

```
<div id="invoice_content">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Html Example</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
 $(document).on('click', "#clone", function () {
 var printContents = $("#invoice_content").clone(true, true);

  //var $data = 'invoice=' + escape(printContents);

  var $data = $(printContents).serialize();

 $.ajax({ url: "functions/insert_html.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"html",
        data:$data,
          success:function(obj){
            alert(obj);
          }
    });      

 });
```

php: save_invoice.php

```
 if (isset($_POST['invoice'])) {

    $html = $_POST['invoice'];  

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `html table` (html) 
     VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($html) . "')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

   mysqli_close($conn);     
  }
```

php: view_invoice.php

```
   if(isset($_GET)){
   $id = $_GET['id'];

   $sql = "SELECT html FROM `html table` WHERE id = '".$id."'";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       $html_id = $row["html"];
        }

    mysqli_close($conn);   

   }

    <div id="invoice_content">                 
       <?php echo $html_id; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't work with `mysqli`. `[object Object]` sounds like a JS issue. With this code `$html_id = $row["html"];` you are overwriting the previous value there, or if there is only one you don't need the `while`. This `$sql = "SELECT html FROM `html table` WHERE id = '".$id."'";` is open to SQL injections. You would be better off using prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: chris85 do you know what JS issue. im stumped or i would not be asking. I did change the mysqli escape string.

Comment: What is being returned if you open developer console can you drill into the object and see what it is?

Comment: when i go to developer console it doesnt show anything

Comment: ive tried var_dump, print_r echo json_decode, They all show [object Object] except json decode which shows nothing

Comment: Sorry i finally figured out how to see in console with console log. In console it shows the same thing [object Object]

Comment: Take a look at this, https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging.

Comment: sorry finally got it to work. i had to use clone().html(). clone() would not go through on its on.